# Implementing a Delegate Method in a Subclass whose Superclass conforms to that protocol Swift

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have incorporated the GoogleMaps API into my app and all is well with that. However after a bit more development I realized I will need to have two different ViewControllers, both showing a `GMSMapView` but each having slightly different functionality. I decided to make a base class which has the common functionality and that base class conforms to `GMSMapViewDelegate`. In this base class, among other things I have:

```
class BaseMapViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapView = GMSMapView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self

        loadMap()
    }

    func loadMap() {
        mapView = GMSMapView(frame: CGRectZero)
        mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid
        self.view = mapView
    }
}

extension BaseMapViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {}
```

One of the subclasses needs to implement `func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)` so I just implement that in the subclass (shown below), but it doesn't register any taps.

```
class SellerMapViewController: BaseMapViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("\(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)")
    }
}
```

I then tried putting that delegate method in the base class and it still didn't register any taps. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong or what I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: it's hard to tell for me without some more code - but a delegate is just a property from another class so I think you should try assigning to the delegate to your sub class instance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there could be a couple things going on:

- Make sure you are setting the superclass as the delegate, not just conforming to the protocol.
- I have done a similar things in my own code, and what I do is implement a dummy function in the superclass that if called prints a message that its subclass needs to implement it, so that the superclass fully implements the delegate method.
- Implement the methods that you need to in your subclass. If the relationship was properly set up in your superclass, the methods will be called in your subclass, overriding the same call in the superclass.

Comment: I've put some code in my original post to reference. I do set the superclass as the delegate in the superclass's viewDidLoad(). I will try to implement the function in the base class like you suggest and then override it in the subclass.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I tried putting `func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("Implement in base class!")
    }` in the base class, and then overriding it in the subclass but it doesn't work

Comment: Oh your code has a different issue. You are actually setting yourself the delegate of an object, but then you call loadMap() and that replaces that map with a new one, which you are not a delegate of. Set yourself as the delegate in loadMap()

Comment: Well... that's something that slipped my mind. So to clarify, I initialize mapView with the GMSMapView Constructor `var mapView = GMSMapView()` and then set the delegate of the mapView to be self `mapView.delegate = self`. Then in loadMap() when I set mapView `mapView = GMSMapView(frame: CGRectZero)`, that, for lack of appropriate terms, overwrites the previous GMSMapView instance and therefore wipes out mapView's delegate property and I must declare that the new object stored in mapView has its delegate as self?

Comment: Yep! Thanks for that. Good news is I'm reassured I was doing the inheritance correctly, and I guess the other good news is I made a mistake that I learned from and won't make again. :) Thanks again!